# cast a date to integer pyspark

Tags: dataframe, date, apache-spark, pyspark, casting

Is is possible to convert a date column to an integer column in a pyspark dataframe? I tried 2 different ways but every attempt returns a column with nulls. What am I missing?

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# DUMMY DATA
simpleData = [("James",34,"2006-01-01","true","M",3000.60),
    ("Michael",33,"1980-01-10","true","F",3300.80),
    ("Robert",37,"1992-07-01","false","M",5000.50)
  ]

columns = ["firstname","age","jobStartDate","isGraduated","gender","salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)
df=df.withColumn("jobStartDate", df['jobStartDate'].cast(DateType()))

# ATTEMPT 1 with cast()

df=df.withColumn("jobStartDateAsInteger1", df['jobStartDate'].cast(IntegerType()))

# ATTEMPT 2 with selectExpr()

df=df.selectExpr("*","CAST(jobStartDate as int) as jobStartDateAsInteger2")
df.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try casting it to a UNIX timestamp using `F.unix_timestamp()`:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# DUMMY DATA
simpleData = [("James",34,"2006-01-01","true","M",3000.60),
    ("Michael",33,"1980-01-10","true","F",3300.80),
    ("Robert",37,"1992-07-01","false","M",5000.50)
  ]

columns = ["firstname","age","jobStartDate","isGraduated","gender","salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)
df=df.withColumn("jobStartDate", df['jobStartDate'].cast(DateType()))

df=df.withColumn("jobStartDateAsInteger1", F.unix_timestamp(df['jobStartDate']))
df.show()

+---------+---+------------+-----------+------+------+----------------------+
|firstname|age|jobStartDate|isGraduated|gender|salary|jobStartDateAsInteger1|
+---------+---+------------+-----------+------+------+----------------------+
|    James| 34|  2006-01-01|       true|     M|3000.6|            1136073600|
|  Michael| 33|  1980-01-10|       true|     F|3300.8|             316310400|
|   Robert| 37|  1992-07-01|      false|     M|5000.5|             709948800|
+---------+---+------------+-----------+------+------+----------------------+
```

Comment: perfect, I just added a couple of details to have the number of days since 1970-01-01 instead of the seconds, but that's what I needed. Tks! df=df.withColumn("jobStartDateAsInteger1", F.unix_timestamp(df['jobStartDate'])/(24*60*60));df=df.withColumn("jobStartDateAsInteger1", df['jobStartDateAsInteger1'].cast(IntegerType()))