# Casting date to integer returns null in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I want to convert a date column into integer using Spark SQL.
I'm following [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64864178/cast-a-date-to-integer-pyspark), but I want to use Spark SQL and not PySpark.

Reproduce the example:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# DUMMY DATA
simpleData = [("James",34,"2006-01-01","true","M",3000.60),
              ("Michael",33,"1980-01-10","true","F",3300.80),
              ("Robert",37,"1992-07-01","false","M",5000.50)
             ]

columns = ["firstname","age","jobStartDate","isGraduated","gender","salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)

df = df.withColumn("jobStartDate", df['jobStartDate'].cast(DateType()))
df = df.withColumn("jobStartDateAsInteger1", F.unix_timestamp(df['jobStartDate']))
display(df)
```

[image]

What I want is to do the same transformation, but using **Spark SQL**. I am using the following code:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("date_to_integer")

%sql
select
seg.*,
CAST (jobStartDate AS INTEGER) as JobStartDateAsInteger2 -- return null value
from date_to_integer seg
```

[image]

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to `CAST` your jobStartDate to `DATE` and then use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` to transform it to UNIX integer.

```sql
SELECT
    seg.*,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST (jobStartDate AS DATE)) AS JobStartDateAsInteger2
FROM date_to_integer seg
```

Comment: I know they recommend the commen to improve the answer and not to say thanks but Thanks Thanks thanks !!!!!!! really Thanks !! 
I had lost hope that it could be done